# Process Exit Code When Process is Killed Forcibly

Tags: windows, process, exit-code

When we kill a process in Windows with Task Manager End Process command, will the process still return an exit code? And if so, what exit code it returns? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, a process is terminated using [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714(VS.85).aspx). The exit code is passed as a parameter to this method.

In the case of the task manager, the exit code is set to 1, but I don't know if it's documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will return non-zero return code which will be wrapped in `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable.

Comment: This depends on the application, there is no standard value AFAIK

Comment: I still don't get it why did somebody downvote this answer :(

Comment: @Armen: nevermind :) IMHO, you shoudn't rely on exit code to detect that application has been terminated or killed (unless this is your own application and you provide special exit code for this case) as ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION (i.e. 1) may be returned in bunch of other situations.