# How to tell if process was forced closed (WaitForExit) has been triggered?

Tags: c#, process, ffmpeg

I am making a call to ffmpeg. Sometimes the call fails and ffmpeg wont exit it will just enter a recursive loop. I have called the WaitForExit mthod.

Further on in the code I am interrogating the standardOutput and standardError. I know that when ffmpeg doesnt exit it produces alot of garbage on the console screen. For that reason I believe when I try and get the standardOutput and standardError the c# code just crashes. Its still being written to. How can I tell if c# has exited the code rathar than the process exiting on its own?

I have tried to look at process.HasExited but it doesnt work. Even though I know c# has exited the process it still comes up as false.

```
            p.StartInfo.FileName = exePathArg;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = argumentsArg;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            p.Start();

            p.WaitForExit(timeToWaitForProcessToExit);

            StreamReader standardOutput = p.StandardOutput;
            StreamReader standardError = p.StandardError;

            retDirects.Add("StandardOutput", standardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            retDirects.Add("StandardError", standardError.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: It is waiting for you to read its output before exiting.  You're doing it the wrong way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not be able to tell unless the process provides some sort of output or error code.  You can look at the ExitCode using:

`p.ExitCode`

The error code is provided by the application, so you'll also have to be aware of what values it might return.

In some cases if the process is killed (e.g. via task manager, ExitCode may be 1, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344923/process-exit-code-when-process-is-killed-forcibly)).

**Update**

After our exchange in the comments, it seems that there were some other issues to address:

If you're confident that the process is actually in an unresponsive state, then killing the process is a good last resort.  There are two ways to "kill" a process with the `Process` class:

- [`Process.Kill()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) - terminate the process (and possibly corrupt data)
- [`Process.CloseMainWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx) - sends close message to the main window (only GUI procs)

If you have a process with a graphical interface, you should use `CloseMainWindow()`.  `CloseMainWindow()` is essentially the same thing as clicking the exit button on a window, so it is safer because it actually asks the program to shut itself down. Note that the process might not actually respond to `CloseMainWindow`, either because it is unresponsive or because it chooses not to, so you may have to use `Kill()` afterwards if that happens.

If your process doesn't have a graphical interface, `Kill()` is the only way to do it.

However, as you asked in the comments about using both, you shouldn't do that unless you tried to use `CloseMainWindow()` and that didn't work.

Comment: Okay well I have tried to access the ExitCode and that throws an error. So I guess I can wrap it in a try,catch block. Shame these classes aren't a bit more robust. I mean the exit code shouldnt throw an error just because the called process has failed.

Comment: InvalidOperationException : Process must exit before requested information can be determined....guess this is becuase the recursive loop that the process enters...!!!

Comment: Ok, now I think I misunderstood your original scenario.  How are you expecting WaitForExit to behave?  It doesn't actually try to stop the process, it will wait for the process to exit on its own.  If you provide a timeout, it will return after that time, otherwise it will wait as long as necessary.  The Kill() and CloseMainWindow() functions are used for actually stopping the process.

Comment: Oh great I didnt know I could do that, so are you saying that I should call WaitForExit(1000) then if I detect that it is stuck in a loop I should then call .Kill and .CloseMainWindow?