# boost::process how to know when a process exited "gracefully or not"?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-process

While waiting for a `boost::process::child`, how can you know if it exited "gracefully or not"?

Let's say I create a processus:

```
boost::process::child child( "myprg.exe", "5000" );
child.wait();
int res = child.exit_code();
```

Where myprg.exe is:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    if ( argc == 2 )
    {
        boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::milliseconds( atoi( argv[1] ) ) );
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: This a MCVE that makes no sense, I agree main should return 0 if successfull.

I see that if someone kills the process while it waits (using `child.terminate` for instance or Windows Process Manager), `child.exit_code()` will return 1.

So, in the end, when `child.exit_code()` is 1, how can I know if this is the value returned by the process's main entry function or if the process was killed?

Is it guaranteed that 1 will mean process was killed? Then program should not return 1 and keep this exit code to identify the specific situation where it was killed and did not exit cleanly?

If not, does `boost::process` API provide something to know if process ended up cleanly or was killed?

Comment: As I remember there isn't a platform independent way, but you could achieve things using process group and handling the CHLD signals. That is: breaking the abstraction of the Boost Process API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, in the end, when `child.exit_code()` is 1, how can I know if this is the value returned by the process's main entry function or if the process was killed?

You can't.

> Is it guaranteed that 1 will mean process was killed?

It depends. As for Windows, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4345139/7703564) answer, it will be 1, but it is documented nowhere. Note that the return code for a killed process is determined by the instance that is terminating the process. For Boost's terminate function, one finds inside detail/windows/terminate.hpp:

> ```
> inline void terminate(child_handle &p)
> {
>     if (!::boost::winapi::TerminateProcess(p.process_handle(), EXIT_FAILURE))
>         boost::process::detail::throw_last_error("TerminateProcess() failed");
>
>     ::boost::winapi::CloseHandle(p.proc_info.hProcess);
>     p.proc_info.hProcess = ::boost::winapi::INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE_;
> }
> ```

So it is returning `EXIT_FAILURE` always, which might be 1. However, one can make a process return any value.

To distinguish whether your process terminated gracefully or not in a completely foolproof and portable manner, you therefore have to implement your own communication mechanism apart from just evaluating the return codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an error handler in child process to return a different exit code. For instance, add [std::set_terminate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate) from STL library :

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::set_terminate([](){ exit(2); });
    if ( argc == 2 )
    {        
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(atoi(argv[1])));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```